# dispatching multiple api calls that depend on each other

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project where I need multiple APIs to be dispatched on the click of my `placeOrderHandler`. The issue that I'm having is that some of these dispatches depend on a previously listed dispatch being completed. Additionally, I get an error stating

```
Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string
```

If  I  haven't received `client_secret` in the frontend by the time

```
const {error: stripeError, paymentIntent} = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret
```

is called. I tried using conditional statements and`setTimeout()` to fix this issue. However, I'm having some issues. I've also never done this, so I'm not even sure if I have set this up correctly. The main issue that I'm having is that if the `if` statement is true and the `setTimeout()` starts once it ends it just loads back the `PlaceOrderScreen.js` (the screen where `placeOrderHandler` is), and then does nothing. How would I get this to repeat until the `if` statement is false and the `else` statement is therefore true? I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to fix this and if there is a better and more efficient way of doing this. Thank you!

```
const paymentCreate = useSelector((state) => state.paymentCreate);
const {client_secret } = paymentCreate;
const elements = useElements();
const stripe = useStripe();

const placeOrderHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
        return;
      }
      const paymentMethodType = 'card';
      const currency = 'usd';
      const {error: backendError} = dispatch(payment(paymentMethodType, currency, cart, userId, ))

      if(client_secret.length === 0){
        setNotLoaded(true); 
        setTimeout(() => { 
          setNotLoaded(false); 
          console.log(client_secret.length)
        }, 30000);}

      else if(client_secret.length > 0){
            const {error: stripeError, paymentIntent} = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret,
              {
                payment_method: {
                  card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),
                  billing_details: {
                    name: cart.billingAddress.fullName,
                  },
                },
              },
            )
            if (stripeError) {
              console.log('stripeError')
              return;
            }
            if (backendError) {
              console.log(backendError)
              return;
            }  
            dispatch(createOrder({ ...cart, orderItems: cart.cartItems }))
            setNotLoaded(true); 
            setTimeout(() => { 
              setNotLoaded(false); 
              const orderId = order._id 
              dispatch(paymentInfo(orderId))

          if (success) {
            const email = userInfo.email
            dispatch(shippingTransaction({shippingMethod, shipment, orderId}))
             .then((shippingMethod) => dispatch(emailOrder(email)))

             if (!order.paymentMethod.fullName) {
              setNotLoaded(true); 
              setTimeout(() => { 
                setNotLoaded(false); 
                props.history.push(`/order/${order._id}`)
                  dispatch({ type: ORDER_CREATE_RESET })  
                }, 10000);}

              else {
                props.history.push(`/order/${order._id}`)
                dispatch({ type: ORDER_CREATE_RESET })  
              }
          }
           
        }, 10000);
      }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout is not the correct approach, for waiting you have to use await or then-catch block(Promise handling). As per my understanding you are using Redux so you can trigger dispatch in useEffect(you would only want to get the client_secrect once) and then use useSelector for accessing the client_secret from the store and then it should be accessible

Comment: Hi, I can't have useEffect within my handler, so I'm not sure how I would do that. I do get ```client_secret``` in my handler from my reducer response from the ```dispatch(payment(paymentMethodType, currency, cart, userId, ))``` action. Also I've tried using ```then()``` but I keep having an issue. I tried using ```then``` by changing ```placeOrderHandler``` into a function and having:

Comment: ```function placeOrderHandler(e) {e.preventDefault(); return function (dispatch) {const paymentMethodType = 'card'; const currency = 'usd'; const {error: backendError} = dispatch(payment(paymentMethodType, currency, cart, userId, )).then((client_secret) => {const {error: stripeError, paymentIntent} = stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret, ...```, but after ```return function (dispatch) {...``` nothing seems to be working/happening

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I read it as a component. In the dispatch then block put all the rest of the code, that will mean after getting client_secret you are performing all tasks. The last comment seems to be correct, you might have to check few things to get it working